# Ending of "Beyond the Sea"

Tags: black-mirror

At the end of the *Black Mirror* season 6 episode "Beyond the Sea", when Cliff returns to the ship seeing what David has done, David just looks at him and offers him a seat.

I can't understand David's emotions and motivation in that scene. Did he kill Lana because he wanted Cliff to lose everyone too? Or was he just too jealous and killed Lana because of that? David looks like he wants to say "You're welcome, Cliff. I did it for you" but Cliff obviously doesn't feel that way, and why would David expect that of him?

(I hope I didn't make any formatting mistakes, I couldn't find out how to mark spoilers, so I guess it's ok to write them?

Comment: My impression is that ya, David wanted Cliff to understand how David felt, but I think the bigger take away here is that David always had a toxic control problem, and while Cliff was surely much more innocent, there was still truth in what David said about Cliff not appreciating his own family and some toxic inclination, given the way Lana admitted to some things, along with both men being fine about how they treated Cliff's son, even though ultimately David doesn't know what healthy love is either.